# Show/Hide dynamically generated divs based on dropdown menu selection

Tags: jquery, image, haml

I'm trying to show/hide dynamically generated divs (`.map-thumb`) based on the selection from dropdown menus `#map-type`, `#map-date`, `#map-county` but am having trouble getting it working. Any ideas?

**HAML**

```
.row#map-thumbnail-wrapper
  .medium-4.columns
    %select#map-type
      %option.filter Type of Program
      - MapChoices['program'].each do |program|
        %option.filter{value: program.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')}= link_to program, '#'
  .medium-4.columns
    %select#map-date
      %option.filter Date Constructed
      - [*2007..Date.today.year].each do |year|
        %option.filter{value: year}= year
  .medium-4.columns
    %select#map-county
      %option.filter County
      - current_locations = @cms_page.children.published.map { |i| cms_page_content(:county, i).capitalize }.keep_if(&:present?).uniq.sort
      - current_locations.each do |county|
        %option.filter{value: county.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')}= link_to county, '#'
.well-thumbnails
  - @cms_page.children.published.in_groups_of(6, false) do |location_row|
    .row
      - location_row.each do |location|
        .medium-2.columns
          - date_created = cms_page_content(:date_created, location)
          .map-thumb.all{class: "#{cms_page_content(:program, location).downcase.gsub(' ', '-')} #{DateTime.parse(date_created).strftime('%Y') if date_created.present?} #{cms_page_content(:county, location).downcase}"}
            - preview_image = cms_page_content('preview.image', location)
            = link_to image_tag(preview_image.file.url(:original)), location.full_path if preview_image
            .map-yellow
            .map-align-mid
              .thumb-text-wrapper
                = cms_page_content(:name, location)
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

  $select = $('#map-date'),
  $select2 = $('#map-type'),
  $select3 = $('#map-county');

  var selectAry = [$select, $select2, $select3];
  $.each(selectAry, function(index, value){
    value.change(function() {
      var filters = $(this).val();
      $('div').hide();
      $('div[class$="' + filters + '"]').show();
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

[HTML Generated](https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/4282dceacc02b14f454f)

Comment: Can you post a link to the HTML? People then can post it to fiddle.js

Comment: Added in the edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#map-date, #map-type, #map-county").change(function (){
        var filters = $(this).val();
        $("div.map-thumb").hide();
        $("div[class*='" + filters + "']").show();
        console.log($("div[class*='"+filters+"']"));
    });
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bcLgE/

There were a couple of issues:

1. One div has a misspelling in the class attribute - "borehold" when it needed to be "borehole"
2. You were hiding all divs, and need to only hide divs with the "map-thumb" class
3. The "$=" selector means that the attribute value needs to end with the given string - you needed "*=", which means that the attribute value needs to contain the given string

Comment: Oops - Left in a console.log! :P

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hidding all the divs, `map-thumb` divs seems to be what you need to hide.

You also need to take into account all select values when calculating the filter.

You need to add a empty value to the first options eg.

```
<option class='filter'>Date Constructed</option>

<option class='filter' value=''>Date Constructed</option>
```

This should be a start:

```
$(function(){

  $select = $('#map-date'),
  $select2 = $('#map-type'),
  $select3 = $('#map-county');

  var selectAry = [$select, $select2, $select3];
  $.each(selectAry, function(index, value){
    value.change(function() {
      var filters = '';
        if($('#map-date').val()) {
            filters += '.' + $('#map-date').val();
        }
        if($('#map-type').val()) {
            filters += '.' + $('#map-type').val();
        }
        if($('#map-county').val()) {
            filters += '.' + $('#map-county').val();
        }
      $('.map-thumb').hide();
        if(filters) {
            $(filters).show();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

[See the working version on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQuc7/)